# Futter: What is the type of SvgPicture?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

```
class CustomProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final **....** svgPic;

  const CustomProfile({
    required this.title,
    required this.svgPic,
```

And then how can I call it?
column ([children: Svg..?..(svgPic)]),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SvgPicture`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg/latest/svg/SvgPicture-class.html)

```dart
class CustomProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final SvgPicture svgPic;
  const CustomProfile({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.svgPic,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        svgPic,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
CustomProfile(
  title: "title",
  svgPic: SvgPicture.asset(""),
)
```

---

Also, you can provide path instead of widget, for this use `String`

```dart
class CustomProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String path;
  const CustomProfile({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.path,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SvgPicture.asset(path),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And use it like

```
CustomProfile(
  title: "",
  path: "",
)
```

Comment: the `Column` inside CustomProfile ?

Comment: welcome, you can find more [about flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

Comment: Thank you! one more question:
    return Column(
      children: [
        svgPic,  **color**
      ],
    );
How can I add color for svg here??? or I can only put it in "svgPic: SvgPicture.asset("...", **color** : Colors.red), "

Comment: First approach  is hard to changes the child, because we are directly passing svg image variable, It would be better if you follow path approach, you can include more optional parameter here. You can wrap with Color Filter but I will suggest to second (path) approach